# Discrete Plot of a complicated function containing Dirac delta or discrete delta function

Tags: plotting, numerics, distributions

I have tried to obtain the discrete plot of the following distribution function, which contains summations and integrations along with Dirac delta function, the Mathematica code of which is given below:

```
A1[l0_, ρ_, n_, m_, q_, h_, M_, 
  v_] := (Sqrt[(2*(q - (Abs[m] + m)/2)!)/(l0^2*q!)])*
  Exp[-((I/(2*h)*M*v*ρ^2)/l0)]*
  Exp[-(ρ^2/(2*l0^2))]*(ρ^2/l0^2)^(Abs[m]/2)*
  LaguerreL[q - (Abs[m] + m)/2, Abs[m], (ρ^2/l0^2)]*(Sqrt[(2*(n - (Abs[m] + m)/2)!)/(l0^2*n!)])*
 Exp[-(ρ^2/(2*l0^2))]*(ρ^2/l0^2)^(Abs[m]/2)*
 LaguerreL[n - (Abs[m] + m)/2, Abs[m], (ρ^2/l0^2)]*ρ 

A2[n_, q_] :=Integrate[A1[1/4, ρ, n, 1, q, 1, 1, 5], {ρ, 0, Infinity}]

E0[q_, m_, w0_, Ω_, 
  h_] := (q + 1/2)*h*(w0 + Ω) + (q - m + 1/2)*
   h (w0 - Ω) + (4 + 1/2)*h*10

p1[l0_, l1_, ρ_, n1_, m_, q_, h_, M_, v_, 
  w0_, Ω_] := (Sqrt[(2*(n1 - (Abs[m] + m)/2)!)/(
   l1^2*n1!)])*Exp[-(ρ^2/(2*l1^2))]*(ρ^2/l1^2)^(Abs[m]/2)*
  LaguerreL[n1 - (Abs[m] + m)/2, Abs[m], (ρ^2/l1^2)]*(Sqrt[(2*(q - (Abs[m] + m)/2)!)/(l1^2*q!)])*
 Exp[(I/(2*h)*M*v*ρ^2 - 
   I/h*l0*E0[q, m, w0, Ω, h]*(l1 - l0)/v)/l1]*
 Exp[-(ρ^2/(2*l1^2))]*(ρ^2/l1^2)^(Abs[m]/2)*
 LaguerreL[q - (Abs[m] + m)/2, Abs[m], (ρ^2/l1^2)]*ρ

p2[q_, n1_] := Integrate[p1[1/4, 1/2, ρ, n1, 1, q, 1, 1, 5, 16, 5], {ρ, 0, 
   Infinity}]

p3[n_, n1_] := Abs[NSum[A2[n, q]*p2[q, n1], {q, 1, 5}]]^2

Z0[n_, m_, w0_, 
  h_, Ω_] := (n + 1/2)*
   h*(w0 + Ω) + (n - m + 1/2)*
   h*(w0 - Ω) + (4 + 1/2)*h*10

f1[β_, n_, m_, w0_, h_, Ω_] := 
 Exp[-β*Z0[n, m, w0, h, Ω]]/4590

D1[w_, n_, n1_, w0_, h_] := DiscreteDelta[w - 2 *h *(-n + n1) *w0]

p4[w_, n_] := NSum[D1[w, n, n1, 16, 1]*p3[n, n1], {n1, 1, 5}]

p5[w_] := NSum[f1[0.01, n, 1, 16, 1, 5]*p4[w, n], {n, 1, 6}]

DiscretePlot[p5[w], {w, -10, 10, 1}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

Mathematica does not give any output and it has not showed any error messages.

Kindly suggest me any correction in codes, I have used, such that I may get the desired plot.

Comment: your function p3 is very slow. When you then run p5 which does multiple sums, it is not surprising that it takes long. I would first work on trying to speed p3 up and you may have a chance.

Comment: @ 
user293787, I have changed the "Sir" and the "I am trying", as suggested..Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @ Dunlop, thak you for your kind response....yes p3  is running very slowly and I observed this, while checking the output of the each separate coomand line. But I have no idea how i can speed up this...is this something like using the "Timing" command

Comment: Maybe use `NIntegrate` instead of `Integrate`?

Comment: The $\delta$-distribution is not a usual function, so its plot is meaningless.

Comment: @user64494....Yes,  the δ function can be replaced by other form such as `(1/pi *x) * Sin [x/ e]` where e tends to zero and adjusting / lowering the value of e i.e. `e = 1 *10 ^-6` or smaller than that, the oscillation may be reduced.